# Solving Ax = B with MathNet in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to do something that should be fairly simple essentially find

x = A \ B

I can do this via

```
var A = Matrix<double>.Build.Sparse(n,m);
// Some code fills this out
var B = Vector<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(signal)
var x = A.PseudoInverse() * B;
```

But this feels very inefficient.  When I try

```
var x = A.QR().Solve(B);
```

I get the error:

> Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: All vectors must have
> the same dimensionality.    at
> MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.Factorization.UserQR.Solve(Vector`1 input, Vector`1 result)    at
> MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Factorization.QR`1.Solve(Vector`1
> input)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, the dimensions of the matrix and vector should be compatible, is there not a way to do this?

In this case "signal" is a double array of length "n".

Comment: What is `signal`, what its dimensions?

Comment: Please include the dimensions of the matrix/vector quantities involved. Also maybe a small sized sample data for our review.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are encountering with `A.QR().Solve(B)` indicates that there is a dimensionality mismatch between matrix A and vector B. To solve the linear system `Ax = B`, the number of columns in A must be equal to the dimension of vector B.

Here's how you can correctly solve the linear system `Ax = B` using `MathNet.Numerics`

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int n = 3; // Define the number of rows in matrix A
        int m = 3; // Define the number of columns in matrix A

        // Create a sparse matrix A with dimensions n x m
        var A = Matrix<double>.Build.Sparse(n, m);

        // Fill in matrix A with your data. For example:
        A[0, 0] = 2.0;
        A[0, 1] = -1.0;
        A[0, 2] = 0.0;
        A[1, 0] = -1.0;
        A[1, 1] = 2.0;
        A[1, 2] = -1.0;
        A[2, 0] = 0.0;
        A[2, 1] = -1.0;
        A[2, 2] = 2.0;

        // Create a dense vector B with the same dimension as the number of rows in A
        var signal = new double[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 }; // Sample data
        var B = Vector<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(signal);

        // Check if the dimensions of A and B are compatible
        if (A.RowCount != B.Count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Matrix A and vector B must have the same number of rows.");
        }

        // Solve the linear system Ax = B using QR decomposition as you wanted
        var x = A.QR().Solve(B);
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

We check if the dimensions of A and B are compatible.

> Make sure to replace the example data in matrix A and vector B with your actual data.

And we solve it!!!!!!